# Creating multiple Java TCP/IP Servers

Tags: java, tcp

I have a Java TCP/IP client and server program that exchanges data based on requests from the clients. I now need to implement multiple instances of this server, with each one holding a subset of the data, with the client still only connecting to the master server. What is the best way to go about this, preferably without multithreading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I agree in that multithreading would be an improvement for high availability and performance, though it's not strictly necessary.)

If you want an scheme like this:

```
                          { ---> slave server 1
client ---> master server { ---> slave server 2
                          { ---> slave server 3
```

... then, you'll have to add to the master server a *client* API, because it will have a double role: As a server, to receive requests from the client/s, and as a client to send requests to the slave servers.

If you have already implemented a client/server communication protocol, then it would be useful to reuse that same protocol for communicate master/slave servers.

You must also address the *binding* matter: How does the master know how many and which slaves there are?

- If they run in the same host, the master itself could start the slaves.
- If they run in different hosts, you'll have to provide this addressing information to the master: Either by static configuration in the master, either by making the slaves send the master an address message as soon as each one of them is started (this implies a complication in the master/slave protocol).

And there's still the *availability* problem: What if one of the slaves shuts down?

- If the network data is wisely distributed between the slaves, in order to produce a high amount of *redundant* data, the problem gets solved just making the master poll the slaves one by one until he gets all the needed data (of corse, this will still serve for just one or two slaves being off simultaneously; if many of the slaves shut down, there can be no gurantee to maintain the data available. Redundancy has a limit).
- If there is no redundancy at all, the master will have to detect this situation, and react properly:

  - If they run in the same host, the master can re-start any of the servers dynamiclly.
  - If they run in different hosts, the master can do no other thing than report the problem to the client through an apporpiate error message.

Data synchronization can be an issue if they share *writable* data. In this case, the master will have to broadcast the same writing to each affected slave.